# Getting Exception while taking input from a file in java

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I have used the scanner class to take input from a given text file. The file format is as follows:

```
NAME: burma14
TYPE: TSP
COMMENT: 14-Staedte in Burma (Zaw Win)
DIMENSION: 5
EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE: GEO 
NODE_COORD_SECTION
1  16.47       96.10
2  16.47       94.44
3  20.09       92.54
4  22.39       93.37
5  25.23       97.24
```

My sample code fragment is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try 
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("burma14.tsp"));

        String line = "";
        int n;

        //three comment lines
        in.nextLine();
        in.nextLine();
        in.nextLine();
        //get n
        line = in.nextLine();
        line = line.substring(11).trim();
        n = Integer.parseInt(line);
        City[] city= new City[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            city[i]= new City();
        }

        //System.out.println("" +n);

        //two comment lines
        in.nextLine();
        in.nextLine();


        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            in.nextInt();
            city[i].x =  in.nextInt();
            city[i].y =  in.nextInt();
            TourManager.addCity(city[i]);
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Basically what I have done here is taking the value from the line DIMENTION and according to this I have stored the x and y co ordinates of different cities into different city objects.

But I am getting the following exception:

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
```

in the line:

```
city[i].x =  in.nextInt();
```

will I need to make any change?

City class is as follows:

```
public class City {
int x;
int y;

// Constructs a randomly placed city
public City(){

 }

// Constructs a city at chosen x, y location
public City(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

// Gets city's x coordinate
public int getX(){
    return this.x;
}

// Gets city's y coordinate
public int getY(){
    return this.y;
}
}
```

Comment: Try to post the city class

Comment: I have provided the city class @Drew Kennedy

Answer (score 4):

Those coordinates in the file are not integers. I would not expect `nextInt` to do what you want with them. Try `nextFloat`.

[EDITED to add:] Actually, `nextDouble` is likely to be a better idea.

Comment: Would `nextFloat()` keep the decimal points at 2? Genuinely curious. :)

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your question. A `float` in Java doesn't have any particular number of decimal places associated with it. If you call `nextFloat` you will get whatever IEEE single-precision floating-point number is nearest to (say) 16.47. It's actually probably a better idea to use `nextDouble` rather than `nextFloat` -- I only wrote `nextFloat` because the last SO question I'd been looking at was about Python and Python calls its only floating-point type `float` :-). So then you'll get the nearest `double` to 16.47.

Comment: Sorry, my question was would `nextFloat` return `16.47` or if it would pad it with more decimal places, say `16.470000`. I'm not so fluent in Java to know all its inner workings, hence the curiosity. I do agree that `nextDouble` is the better choice. :)

Comment: There's no difference between 16.47 and 16.470000 as far as a Java `float` or `double` is concerned. Those are the same number.

Comment: They're the same number, but what if you don't want the padded 0's for whatever reason (to me, I'd have OCD because it's just added garbage to look at). I'm just wondering if a `DecimalFormat` is necessary, or if the JVM is smart enough to not do this.

Comment: If you say `double x = 16.47; double y = 16.4700000;` there is *absolutely no difference* in the values of `x` and `y`. The same applies if they get their values from a `Scanner` that reads `16.47` in one case and `16.4700000` in the other. If you are generating *output*, you can control whether values get written with a fixed number of decimal places (in which case you'd get an appropriate number of 0s) or with as many decimal places as are needed to display them accurately (in which case you wouldn't). And yes, `DecimalFormat` is one tool for controlling that.

Comment: Agree wih @GarethMcCaughan. Why are you worried about the precision? Do you need these numbers printed somewhere ?